# Python Beginner split String in two strings

Tags: python, string, split

I have an IP-Range `192.0.0.2-4` as string and want to split it in two new strings

```
ip_start = '192.0.0.2'
ip_end = '192.0.0.4'
```

so I have to search for `"-"` in `"192.0.0.2-4"` and split there, but how can I make the second string?

Comment: can you post the string that you want to split?

Comment: @JulienSpronck: it's there in the first sentence.

Comment: Is the range always limited to the last byte of the address?

Comment: @MartijnPieters yes it is always limited to the last byte

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the range is always limited to the last byte (octet) of the address, split on the last dot of the address and replace it with your end value:

```
ip_start, _, end_value = iprange.partition('-')
first_three = ip_start.rpartition('.')[0]
ip_end = '{}.{}'.format(first_three, end_value)
```

I used [`str.partition()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.partition) and [`str.rpartition()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.rpartition) here as you only need to split just once; the methods are a little faster for that case. The methods return 3 strings, always; everything before the partition string, the partition string itself, and everything after. As we only need the first string of the `.` partition, I used indexing there to select it for assignment.

Since you don't need to keep that dash or dot I assigned those to a variable named `_`; that's just a convention and is used to signal that you'll ignore that value altogether.

Demo:

```
>>> iprange = '192.0.0.2-4'
>>> iprange.partition('-')
('192.0.0.2', '-', '4')
>>> iprange.partition('-')[0].rpartition('.')
('192.0.0', '.', '2')
>>> ip_start, _, end_value = iprange.partition('-')
>>> first_three = ip_start.rpartition('.')[0]
>>> ip_end = '{}.{}'.format(first_three, end_value)
>>> ip_start
'192.0.0.2'
>>> ip_end
'192.0.0.4'
```

For completeness sake: you can also use the [`str.rsplit()` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.rsplit) to split a string from the right, but you need to include a limit in that case:

```
>>> first.rsplit('.', 1)
['192.0.0', '2']
```

Here the second argument, `1`, limits the split to the first `.` dot found.

Answer (score 1):

You could build up the second string by using the piece from the "first" IP address.

```
>>> def getIPsFromClassCRange(ip_range):
...     # first split up the string like you did
...     tmp = ip_range.split("-")
...     # get the fix part of the IP address
...     classC = tmp[0].rsplit(".", 1)[0]
...     # append the ending IP address
...     tmp[1] = "%s.%s" % (classC, tmp[1])
...     # return start and end ip as a useful tuple
...     return (tmp[0], tmp[1])
...
>>> getIPsFromClassCRange("192.0.0.2-4")
('192.0.0.2', '192.0.0.4')
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is 3 steps solution, 
using a [generator expression](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/) :

```
def ip_bounds(ip_string):
    """Splits ip address range like '192.0.0.2-4'
    into two ip addresses : '192.0.0.2','192.0.0.4'"""

    # split ip address with last '.' 
    ip_head, ip_tail = ip_string.rsplit('.', 1)

    # split last part with '-'
    ip_values = ip_tail.split('-')

    # create an ip address for each value
    return tuple('{}.{}'.format(ip_head,i) for i in ip_values)

ip_start, ip_end = ip_bounds('192.0.0.2-4')
assert ip_start == '192.0.0.2'
assert ip_end == '192.0.0.4'
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer so we can better understand what it does and how it works.